# Filter a substring in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In `kotlin` I'd like to filter a string and return a substring of only valid characters.  Say we have valid characters,

```
valid = listOf('A', 'B', 'C')
```

How can I define a `fcn` in kotlin in the most succinct way to filter a string and only retain valid characters?  For example,

```
'ABCDEBCA' --> 'ABCBCA'
'AEDC'     --> 'AC'
```

Having trouble finding a canonical way to do this without resorting to using an array of string.

```
import kotlin.text.filter

class Test(){
    val VALID = listOf("A", "B", "C")

    fun filterString(expression: String): String{
         expression.filter(x --> !VALID.contains(x)) #Doesn't work
    }
}
```

The [filter docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/filter.html) doesn't show any examples specifically for spring manipulation.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was at -1, have an upvote.

Comment: I agree! I ended up here, because I had a similar issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val VALID = setOf('A', 'B', 'C') // lookup in a set is O(1), whereas it's O(n) in a list. The set must contain Chars, not Strings
val expression = "ABCDEFEDCBA"
val filtered = expression.filter { VALID.contains(it) }
println(filtered)
// ABCCBA
```

Or

```
val VALID = setOf('A', 'B', 'C')

fun filterString(expression: String) = expression.filter { it in VALID }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val expression = "ABCDEFEDCBA"
    val filtered = filterString(expression)
    println(filtered)
    // ABCCBA
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Part of my problem as well was not using characters.  IE "(" instead of '(' in my VALID delcaration.

Comment: Doesnt work when you use " " inside setOf(). Works perfect with ' '

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a long set of chars you could join them in a String and convert it to a Set:

```
val VALID = "ABC".toSet()

fun filterString(expression: String) = expression.filter { it in VALID }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val expression = "ABCDEFEDCBA"
    val filtered = filterString(expression)
    println(filtered)
    // ABCCBA
}
```